Handling BrainVision matlab files with ECG data in EEGLAB
I have 217 preprocessed BrainVision matlab files (.mat) with ECG data in them. I've been having trouble creating a study for these. I know BioSig works for ECG data, but it doesn't seem to work for BrainVision files.
" struct with fields:
   message: 'Unrecognized field name "brainvision".'"

bva-io handles brainvision files but didn't work either, I believe because of the ECG data.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
